# status line in iterm integrated with tmux

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm, tmux

I was trying to set the iTerm and tmux integration and found that panes could be displayed as iTerm2 window splits, if I run `tmux -CC`. But there is a problem, this 'simulation' of tmux does not have the status line, at least I was not able to find manual how to accomplish that.

If you know the way to do that, please, tell me how, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Showing a status bar is currently [not supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/XuL2UpPRkAk) on iTerm2. A version of the status bar is coming to [iTerm2 3.3](https://www.iterm2.com/3.3/documentation-status-bar.html).

But I am not sure if it will pick up the `powerline-status` bar instead of its own during `tmux` sessions.